# Train one ML model on predictions of another ML model

Tags: machine-learning

I am using a heavy machine learning model to automatically label my dataset. After that I train a lighter and faster machine learning model on this dataset (on predictions of heavy ML model). How is this technique called?

It is very similar to knowledge distillation, when you add similarity loss to original loss function and train a lighter model (student) to produce the same logits as heavy model (teacher). But in my case I literally train light model on predictions of heavy model, so I guess this is not just a variation of knowledge distillation, this is something different. I need to know the name of this technique to search for papers on this topic on arxiv.

Comment: [Ensemble](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ensemble_learning)?

Comment: No, ensemble is when you combine several models into a single one. I am not combining heavy and light model. I just use heavy model to automatically label my dataset

Comment: what you are describing is similar to [Stacking](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.StackingClassifier.html). In sklearn docs (it is put under Ensemble).

Comment: But stacking is also assumes that ML models will be combined, and both models will be used for final prediction. In my case only 1 model (light) used for final prediction

Comment: Your question [is not about programming](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). In other SE sites you'll have more chances of finding better answers, and is more likely that future readers will find your question. [Which Stack Exchange website for machine learning and computational algorithms?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130524/which-stack-exchange-website-for-machine-learning-and-computational-algorithms)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is called "offline knowledge distillation" (see Figure 8 of [Gou et al. 2021](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11263-021-01453-z))

Comment: Yeah, it seems like my method is somewhere between offline knowledge distillation and pseudo-labeling. Thanks for help